# How to write to a CSV file to dump into s3 in an AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python, csv, aws-lambda

I'm working to code a Lambda in Python that will hit an Aurora RDS Postgres database and export the results of it as a CSV file into a S3 bucket in the same account that the lambda is in.  I've been able to get it to the point that it is hitting the database and getting the results, but I'm having trouble getting it to export as the csv to the bucket.

Note: I'm still very much a Python novice, but the best way to learn is solving problems.

```
    import boto3
    import psycopg2
    import pandas
    import calendar
    import datetime
    import time
    import json
    import io
    import csv 
    from io import StringIO
    from datetime import date
    from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

    def copyresults(bucket, select_query, filename):
        cdscur.execute(select_query)
        pgquery_result = cdscur.fetchall()
        
        f_handle =  open('tmp/temp.csv', newline='')
        writer = csv.writer(f_handle)
        header = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'field_4', 'field_5', 'field_6']
        writer.writerow(header)
        
        for row in pgquery_result:
            writer.writerow(row)
            
        resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        resource.Object(bucket, '{filename}.csv').put(Body= f_handle, Key=cds_key)
        
    # Set the text of the query against the common datastore
    pgquery = 'SELECT * FROM table'


    cds_bucket = 'bucket-name' 
    cds_result_file = '%scompanyouput' % (dt_f.strftime('%B%Y'))
    cds_key = '/data-key/'

    pghost = 'host-name'
    pgdatabase = 'db-name'
    pguser = 'username'
    pgpassword = 'password'

    try: 
        cdsconnection = psycopg2.connect(host = pghost, dbname = pgdatabase, user = pguser, password =     
            pgpassword) 
        cdscur = cdsconnection.cursor()
    
        copyresults(cds_bucket, pgquery, cds_result_file) 
    
        cdscur.close

    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to complete query.')
        print(e)
```

This is my code as currently exists.  I've tried various suggestions from other similar questions that I found through Google searches.  None of them have worked.

Current error is:
Function Logs
Unable to complete query.
not writable

Comment: Close the CSV file before calling [upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_file.html) (or otherwise uploading the CSV).